# How do I program a JPanel such that the graphics are always visible?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

JPanel graphics are not fully visible [swing](/questions/tagged/swing)

I am attempting to program an event scheduling system. I have coded a SchedulePanel class that contains a grid that I drew directly onto the panel.

```
public class SchedulePanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        static final int originX = 0;
        static final int originY = 0;
        static final int cellSide = 50;

        static final int cols = 5;
        static final int rows = 5;

        public SchedulePanel() {
            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(cols * cellSide, rows * cellSide));
            setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            // this for loop draws horizontal lines that separate the rows in
            // the
            // grid
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                g.drawLine(originX, originY + (i * cellSide),
                        originX + (cols * cellSide), originY + (i * cellSide));
            }
            // this for loop draws vertical lines that separate the columns in
            // the
            // grid
            for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
                g.drawLine(originX + (i * cellSide), originY,
                        originX + (i * cellSide), originY + (rows * cellSide));
            }

        }
    }
```

When I add this panel to the main panel containig another component I can only see the top right corner of the grid. How do I make it so that all of my graphics are visible?

```
public class EventSchedulerGUI extends JPanel {

    RoomPanel roomPanel;
    SchedulePanel schedulePanel;
    JList<Room> roomList;

    public EventSchedulerGUI() {
        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(layout);
        roomPanel = new RoomPanel();

        schedulePanel = new SchedulePanel();
        schedulePanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

        add(roomPanel);
        add(schedulePanel);

    }
```

Comment: Use layouts in a smarter way. FlowLayout is very limited in what it can do, and in how it works. Consider giving EventSchedulerGUI a BorderLayout and placing your schedule panel in the center position, the room panel elsewhere, perhaps in the PAGE_END  position.

Comment: Your `SchedulePanel` should be defining acceptable sizing hints (starting with `preferredSize`), it's then up to the layout mangers to figure out how to accomodate this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've already tried using the BorderLayout, but after experimenting with some other layouts I found that the GridLayout functioned a little better in my program. I would still like to understand why the Border and Flow layouts didn't work.

Comment: Define "fully visible".

Comment: *I would still like to understand why the Border and Flow layouts didn't work.* - Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to understand the rules of each layout. 1) the FlowLayout respects the preferred size of a component. You didn't specify a preferred size so the default size of (10, 10) is used because by default a FlowLayout has a gap of 5 pixels between components added to the panel. 2) The BorderLayout only allows one components to be added to the CENTER which is the default if you don't specify a constraint.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your component should be defining it's acceptable sizing hints, these are then used by the layout managers to make decisions about how best to layout your component.

As a starting point, you should override `getPreferredSize`, for example...

```
public class SchedulePanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    static final int originX = 0;
    static final int originY = 0;
    static final int cellSide = 50;

    static final int cols = 5;
    static final int rows = 5;

    public SchedulePanel() {
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(cols * cellSide, rows * cellSide));
        setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        // I generally prefer to calculate this based on the
        // needs of the component and it's data, but you get the
        // idea
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // this for loop draws horizontal lines that separate the rows in
        // the
        // grid
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            g.drawLine(originX, originY + (i * cellSide),
                    originX + (cols * cellSide), originY + (i * cellSide));
        }
        // this for loop draws vertical lines that separate the columns in
        // the
        // grid
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            g.drawLine(originX + (i * cellSide), originY,
                    originX + (i * cellSide), originY + (rows * cellSide));
        }

    }
}
```

## Why `override` instead of calling `setXxxSize`?

Because it's the component's responsibility to make these determinations, not the callers.  It's the callers responsibility to figure out how to accomodate them.

Also, you don't want someone coming along and modifying the sizing hints, that just messes everything up.